# Pyproject dependencies vs build-system requires?

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

Just started looking at using pyproject.toml for a repository of mine, but can't discern the different between the dependencies key and the build-system requires key? Which one replaces requirements.txt?

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer comes a little late. The pyproject.toml section `dependencies`  replaces the requirements.txt. The pyproject.toml section `build-system requires` is the requirements to build your package.
You can find more inforamation in the [Dependencies Management in Setuptools].[1](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html)